# Formatter error: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

I get an error during calling method from net.tcp service.

**This is my error message:**

client.MyMethod(param): The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:Result. The InnerException message was 'Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''. '.  Please see InnerException for more details."

**Inner exception:**
"System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''. "

**client object is here:**

```
client = new ChannelFactory<IContract>("MyExService").CreateChannel();
```

**Binding definition:**

```
<client>
  <endpoint name="MyExService" address="net.tcp://server:12707/"   
   binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcp" contract="path.IContract" >
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

I cannot debug this webservice. Any idea what can be wrong?
I don't know what the *Result* from *http://tempuri.org/:Result* is.

Comment: I don't know what exactly happened ;]
I run the service localy and I don't get an error any more.
I suppouse, there was some problem with connecting to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason**: service didn't work.
**Solution**: run service localy: RGB -> create new instance.